# Regular expression [^ .]+

Tags: regex

Hi just trying to understand how to interpret [^.]+ below. I read it as 'match for not (a space or any character), repeated 1+ times. It logically seems the ^ shouldn't be necessary to me. Please clarify, thanks!

```
numbers = c("one", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten")
numbers_match = str_c("(", str_c(numbers, collapse = "|"), ") [^ .]+")
has_number <- str_subset(sentences, numbers_match)
str_extract(has_number, numbers_match) %>% head(10)
```

Comment: `[^.]` is equivalent to *"match any character that isn't a dot"*

Answer (score 3):

`.` does not mean "any character" inside `[]`, it's just a literal dot. So `[^ .]` means "not a space or dot".